Pycharm setting breakpoints fails in frida's on_message method
Breakpoint success outside on_message. Breakpoint failure in on_message method
import frida
def on_message(message, data):
    if message['type'] == 'send': # PyCharm breakpoint failed, pdb breakpoint success
        print('1 message')
    else:
        print('2')

# breakpoint success
jscode = 'Java.perform(function () { send("test") }); '
device = frida.get_usb_device()
app = device.get_frontmost_application()
session = device.attach(app.pid)
script = session.create_script(jscode)
script.on('message', on_message)
script.load()


Please provide some description of the actual problem and the environment you're running this in. As it stands, this question is destined for closure. Also, this problem does not appear to have anything to do with PyCharm specifically - what behaviour do you see if you run this script outside PyCharm?

To my experience this is a normal behavior. Breakpoints in PyCharm in callback functions of Frida have never worked. BTW: on which OS have you experienced this problem (Windows/Linux/MacOS)? I would also mention in the question that  breakpoint works with pdb, and not hide this important info in a comment in the source code.
